# Determine current position of element positioned with jQuery Sortable plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, jquery-ui-sortable, move

I use jQuery UI Sortable plug-in to move elements on my page. My elements are divided into three columns and three rows. When I move an object, I want to know the position of my element (first row-first column, first row third column, etc.).

Here's an example: [jQuery UI Sortable plug-in](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid)

Comment: Please show us the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

When you move an element, the `sortchange` event is fired. The second parameter of this event contains information about the element that was moved. The property you're looking for is `.offset`, which gives you the position of the element that was just moved. To get the row, divide `ui.position.top` by the `height` of the the element and add one. To get the column, divide `ui.position.left` by the `width` of the the element, and add one.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/BfzsJ/

Script:

```js
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();

$( '#sortable' ).bind( 'sortchange', function( event, ui ) {

    var width = event.target.clientWidth,
        height = event.target.clientHeight,
        top = this.offsetTop,
        left = this.offsetLeft;

    document.getElementById( 'position' ).textContent = 
        ' row: ' + Math.floor( ( Math.abs( ui.offset.top + top ) / height ) + 1 ) 
        + ' col: ' + Math.floor( ( Math.abs( ui.offset.left + left ) / width ) + 1 ) ;

} );
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="position">row: n/a col: n/a</div>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li><!--
    --><li class="ui-state-default">2</li><!--
    --><li class="ui-state-default">3</li><!--
    --><li class="ui-state-default">4</li><!--
    --><li class="ui-state-default">5</li><!--
    --><li class="ui-state-default">6</li><!--
    --><li class="ui-state-default">7</li><!--
    --><li class="ui-state-default">8</li><!--
    --><li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
#sortable { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 325px;
}

#sortable li { 
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 4em;
    height: 100px; 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px; 
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, finding this a bit buggy when I tried it on jsfiddle. I can move the 2 into the centre and the row/col is reported as 2/1. Works for the mostpart though

Comment: @EdSykes Yeah, I noticed that too. It's just a starting point and needs some work still.